# Java vs C# Millisecond Timestamp Generation

Tags: java, c#, datetime, unix-timestamp, epoch

I have the following Java code which creates a millisecond timestamp and places it in a Mongo database

```
private static long ukTimeStringToUtcMillis(String s) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = makeSimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    try {
        return sdf.parse(s).getTime();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

private static SimpleDateFormat makeSimpleDateFormat(String s) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(s);
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));
    return sdf;
}
```

and I create the timestamp for "2015/10/01 00:00:00" using simply

```
long l = ukTimeStringToUtcMillis("2015-10-01T00:00:00.000");
```

this gives me a timestamp of 1443654000000 [Java], using http://www.epochconverter.com/epoch/timezones.php?epoch=1443654000000&tz=Europe%2FLondon we can see that this gives "Thursday October 01, 2015 00:00:00 (am) in time zone Europe/London (BST)".

Now, my problem (or lack of understanding!) is that I have equivalent code in C# to do the conversion to Unix Epoch milliseconds

```
public static class DateTimeHelpers
{
    public static DateTime UnixEpoch()
    {
        return new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    }

    public static DateTime FromMillisecondsSinceUnixEpoch(long milliseconds)
    {
        return UnixEpoch().AddMilliseconds(milliseconds).ToUniversalTime();
    }

    public static long ToMillisecondsSinceUnixEpoch(DateTime dateTime)
    {
        return (long)(dateTime - UnixEpoch()).TotalMilliseconds;
    }
}
```

which to get the milliseconds for "2015/10/01 00:00:00" I do

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2015, 10, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
long l = DateTimeHelpers.ToMillisecondsSinceUnixEpoch(dt);
```

But this gives `l = 1443657600000` [C#] which converted http://www.epochconverter.com/epoch/timezones.php?epoch=1443657600000&tz=Europe%2FLondon gives "Thursday October 01, 2015 01:00:00 (am) in time zone Europe/London (BST)".

1. Why is this giving +01:00?
2. How can I get the C# code to produce *exactly* what the Java does?

It is very important that I can query the timestamps in the database consistently from both languages but currently C# is giving me an hour discrepancy.

Thanks for your time.

---

The Answer: To get this to work I changed the method

```
public static long ToMillisecondsSinceUnixEpoch(DateTime dateTime)
{
    return (long)(dateTime.ToUniversalTime().Subtract(UnixEpoch())).TotalMilliseconds;
}
```

and used

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2015, 10, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
lonf l = DateTimeHelpers.ToMillisecondsSinceUnixEpoch(dt);
```

Note the lack of `DateTimeKind` and the use of `ToUniversalTime()` in the new `ToMillisecondsSinceUnixEpoch()` method.

However I don't really appreciate what `DateTime` was doing before I used `ToUniversalTime()`. Using `DateTimeKind.UTC` on the creation of the initial `DateTime` should have done this? Any clarification on what is going on with `DateTime` in this (to me bizarre case) would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think, it doesn't work because you don't use the same timezone in Java and C#.

In your Java sample, you are applying a conversion in the method `makeSimpleDateFormat` with the usage of `sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"))`. So you're input date `2015/10/01 00:00:00` is converted to `30 Sep 2015 23:00:00 GMT` (or Epoch Unix Time `1443654000000`).

But in C# code, your are just using the UTC date. This explains the 1 hour difference. You have to apply an equivalent conversion to retrieve the same Epoch Unix Time. The following snippet will fix your code:

```
public static long ToMillisecondsSinceUnixEpoch(DateTime dateTime)
{
    DateTimeOffset offset = new DateTimeOffset(dateTime, new TimeSpan(1,0,0));
    return (long)(offset - UnixEpoch()).TotalMilliseconds;
}
```

And used it with:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2015, 10, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
long l = DateTimeHelpers.ToMillisecondsSinceUnixEpoch(dt);
```